# Vertically open file mark in Vim

Tags: vim

I have set a file mark in `$MYVIMRC`. Is there a way for me to open this marked file vertically? Although the description of `:vertical` does not look like it would work, I did try `` :vert `V `` which did not work.

This seems to work: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Is there a better way?

Comment: ``:vert `V`` doesn't work because ``'`V'`` doesn't split the window. ``:vsp | norm `V`` should also work but isn't much better than your solution.

Comment: @EtanReisner why did you not make this an answer?

Comment: Started out with just the explanation of :vert not working. Added the other possibility as an afterthought. I've duplicated it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`` :vert `V `` doesn't work because ```V`` doesn't split the window.

`` :vsp | norm `V `` should also work but isn't much better than your solution.

Comment: I just cannot win here can I. =)